# Access item in list custom class

Tags: c#

Ok, I have this code:

```
URLs.Add(new URL(str.URL, str.Title, browser));
```

and this is the URL class:

```
public class URL
{
    string url;
    string title;
    string browser;
    public URL(string url, string title, string browser)
    {
        this.url = url;
        this.title = title;
        this.browser = browser;
    }
}
```

Now, how do I access the URL title..?
ie., Property of URLs[0]...? When I print URLs[0].ToString, it just gives me the Namespace.URL.
How do I print the variables inside of the URL class?

Comment: You've not given enough information to be able to answer the question.  What sort of object is `URLs`?

Comment: @freefaller, he said it in the title - a list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upgrade your class to expose public properties:

```
 public class URL 
    { 
        public string Url { get; set; } 
        public string Title { get; set; } 
        public string Browser { get; set; } 
        public URL(string url, string title, string browser) 
        { 
            this.Url = url; 
            this.Title = title; 
            this.Browser = browser; 
        } 
    }
```

Then access your properties like so:

```
foreach(var url in URLs)
{
  Console.WriteLine(url.Title);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things - by default, all members of a class will be private - meaning that they're not accessible to outside callers. If you wish them to be available, mark them as public:

```
public string url;
```

Then you can do:

```
URLs[0].url;
```

If you wish to simple pipe-out the structure, you can override ToString, by adding a method like follows:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return string.format("{0} {1} {2}", url, title, browser);
}
```

then simply call:

```
URLs[0].ToString();
```